# How can I align to the end of a bootstrap navbar one of my link

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpYeY.png)

I'm tring to use a bootstrap navbar and I'd like align one Link, the last, to the right.
I searched on the documentation, but i didn't find any usefull answer. Hope you can Help me

Comment: `ml-auto` class to that last link which will occupy the remainign space and therefor push that element to the far right.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the property ms-auto, ms-right, or ms-left depending on what side you're trying to align towards.
here is an example, I was just working on that

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active" aria-current="page">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio-overview.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

in my case they align towards the right, but if you change it for ms-right the links will move to the right.

hope that works for you!

Comment: It worked, than you!